# Tutorials on Nhibernate and linq to nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am thinking of trying out Nhibernate and possibly the linq to Nhibernate extension.

Should I first go through just the regular Nhibernate first and then proceed to the linq extension?

Also does anyone have any good tutorials on linq to Nhibernate I am having trouble finding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy the book [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book#), You can get just the PDF for about 16 quid, BARGIN!

> Buy the book as it goes through how to
>   set up a website using asp.net and
>   asp.net MVC showing how to implement
>   modules for session management. You
>   will not be disappointed and for 16
>   quid you will save alot of time.

As a further note I have been usuing Nhibernate for just over a year and found it hard going looking at blogs, tutorials and sample apps etc. Because there is a lot of information regarding NHibernate on the web I found a lot of it is now outdated, you find a lot of contradictions and code that just does not work.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my answer. I also bought this and its indispensable.

Comment: Hmm I finding this book very hard to follow. I also don't like the fact that it really does not seem to have like a hellworld to get your feet wet. It goes write into so many classes and every sort of relationship and yet I have not done anything like inserting data or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Linq-to-NHibernate wraps around NHibernate's Criterion API for creating queries. I think it's important to understand Nhibernate's essentials, and how the other optional query methods work. After that, it's mostly a matter of just understanding known issues and unimplemented parts of the L2N implementation.

Of course, you should look at NH3 if possible, as their LINQ support is much better and integrated into NH core. I think under the covers, L2N uses the QueryOver API added in NH3.

[NHibernate Reference Documentation (for NH v3)](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html)

[LINQ to NHibernate, JQuery/jqGrid SubGrid, HQL and ICriteria (for NH v2.1)](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/LINQ-to-NHibernate-JQuery-jqGrid-SubGrid-HQL-and-ICriteria.aspx)

[A nice  beginning to end guide of getting NH and L2N up and running (for NH v2.1)](http://emiajnet.blogspot.com/2009/04/fluent-nhibernate-and-linq2nhibernate.html)

Comment: So Nhibernate 3.0 ships with linq support? If that is the case then I won't bother with the linq to nhibernate wrapper.

Comment: Yes, in 3.0 Linq is no longer a separate library. However, I must mention that even in 3.0 all Linq features are still not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Fluent NHibernate, which lets you create your mappings in code, rather than XML (HBM files).

I started out by reading the short and clear documentation from Fluent NHibernate.

There is also the Mastering NHibernate series at [TekPub](http://www.tekpub.com), which requires a purchase or subscription. It covers the basics and some intermediate material.

Finally, once you've created some tests/samples, try out the [NhProf](http://www.nhprof.com) -- the NHibernate profiler. Though somewhat costly, it is truly an indispensible tool to working with NH -- for identifying bottlenecks, understanding how and when queries are executed, and improving performance in general.